# Kubectl apply -f mongo-secret.yaml is not creating the secret inside my config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

When I run the below command,

```
Kubectl apply -f mongo-secret.yaml
```

I'm thrown the following error,

[image]

Below is the Secret configuration I used,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username: dXNlcm5hbWU=
  mongo-root-password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Secret` instead of `secret` in the `kind` field.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username: dXNlcm5hbWU=
  mongo-root-password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Comment: Thanks @Emruz also found out I needed to pass --validate=false to create secret

Comment: `--validate=false` is not a solution. This will let you create invalid resources which may cause issue in the cluster. Instead you should fix the actual reason.